# Solving a system that is a combination of quadratic and linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, quadratics

The problem is as follows:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \frac{45}4 \\ 
(x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2 + (z-1)^2 = \frac{45}4 \\ 
x + 2y + z - 4 = 0
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Comment: Next time, show your **own** work.

Comment: okey, as for the problem I actually did the same as the people below but I miss-put some signs so it didn't come well, now Ive seen where I was wrong. Next time I'm going to do it right. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

from the second equation we get $$x^2+y^2+z^2-2(x+y+z)=\frac{45}{4}-3$$
using the first equation with zhis obove we obtain
$$\frac{45}{4}-2(x+y+z)=\frac{45}{4}-3$$ from here we get
$$x+y+z=\frac{3}{2}$$
and
$$x+2y+z=4$$
can you get further?

Comment: I've got it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Expanding equation (2),

$x^2-2x+1+y^2-2y+1+z^2-2z+1=\frac{45}4$

$\frac{45}4 - 2x - 2y - 2z + 3 = \frac{45}4$

$2x + 2y + 2z = 3$

$x+y+z=\frac{3}2$

Using this equation and equation (3) you can eliminate x and z to find y. Then find x and z.